# Conversion hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: c

I've already written a program, but it's a bit incorrect.
I will be very grateful if you show me how to fix it.

So, here is the trouble:
You have to convert the number from hexadecimal to decimal form.
The main problem is that program must CALCULATE MANUALLY the number , instead of using a format specification ( as i did )

I apologize for possible inaccuracies and mistakes in English, I am just starting to familiarize myself with programming))

There is my variant:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 20

int main(void) {

    system("chcp 1251");
    char str[SIZE][SIZE], (*pstr)[SIZE];
    pstr = str;
    char* pcode;
    int kst;
    printf("Specify the number of lines you want to enter: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &kst);
    getchar();
    while (kst > SIZE)
    {
        printf("You have exceeded the allowed value (the number of lines must be less than 20): ");
        scanf_s("%d", &kst);
        getchar();
    }
    while (kst < 1)
    {
        printf("You entered a number that is too small, try entering a number between 1 and 20:");
        scanf_s("%d", &kst);
        getchar();
    }


    int isXDigit;

    printf("\nEnter the lines:\n\n");

    while (pstr < str + kst)
    {
        isXDigit = 1;

        gets_s(*pstr);

        for (pcode = *pstr; *pcode != '\0'; pcode++){
            
            if (isxdigit(*pcode) == 0){
                **pstr = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        pstr++;
    }
    printf("\nThe result\n");

    unsigned long long sixteen;

    for (pstr = str; pstr < str + kst; pstr++)
    {
        if (**pstr == 0)
            printf("16: The error!\n");
        else {
            sixteen = strtoull (*pstr, NULL, 16);
            printf("16: %#020llx | 10: %llu\n", sixteen, sixteen);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read a string, convert each character to the corresponding `int` value (so e.g. `'5'` becomes `5`, `'e'` becomes `14`, etc.). Then just add it all together to a single `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long long hexToNum(const char *hexSTR)
{
    const char *digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    const char *found = NULL;
    unsigned long long result = 0;

    while(*hexSTR)
    {
        result *= 0x10;
        if(found = strchr(digits, toupper((unsigned char)*hexSTR)))
            result += found - digits;
        else { result = 0; break;}
        hexSTR++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Textual representation of a number

“Hexadecimal” and “decimal” (and “octal” and “binary” et cetera) are all *textual representations* of a number.

That is, we *write* numbers with a **radix**, but a number exists independently of any particular representation.

That is why `0xA` equals `10` equals `012` equals `0b1010` (hexadecimal, decimal, octal, and binary representations).

Remember in grade school when you were taught digit places? That is because a number is a polynomial representation of a value.

→ `123` equals `100` + `20` + `3`

Or, written as a polynomial:

→ `1`×10<sup>2</sup> + `2`×10<sup>1</sup> + `3`×10<sup>0</sup>

That `10` is the **radix**. If we change the radix, the number gets written differently. The following, even though it has the same digits, is a *totally different* number:

→ `1`×16<sup>2</sup> + `2`×16<sup>1</sup> + `3`×16<sup>0</sup>

We can see this by doing the math.

- 3×16<sup>0</sup> is `3`
- 2×16<sup>1</sup> is `32`
- 1×16<sup>2</sup> is `256`
- 256 + 32 + 3 is `291`

### Dissecting a number to a polynomial representation with radix

To get the least-significant digit of a number, you simply take the **remainder** of dividing it by the radix:

→ 123 ÷ 10 is `12` with a remainder of `3`

You can repeat this process to get every digit in the given radix:

→ 12 ÷ 10 is `1` with a remainder of `2`
 → 1  ÷ 10 is `0` with a remainder of `1`

So the digits, radix 10, of 123 are, least-significant to most-significant, `3`, `2`, and `1`. We write this as `123`.

Suppose we take a radix of 16?

→ 123 ÷ 16 is `7` with a remainder of `11` (which we write as `B`)
 → 7   ÷ 16 is `0` with a remainder of `7`

So the hexadecimal (radix == 16) value of 123 is `7B`.

Suppose we take a radix of 8?

→ 123 ÷ 8 is `15` with remainder `3`
 → 15  ÷ 8 is `1` with remainder `7`
 → 1   ÷ 8 is `0` with remainder `1`

So the octal (radix == 8) value of 123 is `173`.

In C the operators for getting the quotient and remainder are `/` and `%`:

- 42 / 10 is `4` (quotient)
- 42 % 10 is `2` (remainder)

### Building a number from a polynomial representation with radix

If you are given a textual number representation and wish to build that into an actual numeric value, you only need to know the radix and have access to multiplication and addition.

For example, given `2` `7` `B`:

```
 0 * 16 + 2   →    0 + 2   →  2
 2 * 16 + 7   →   32 + 7   →  39
39 * 16 + 11  →  624 + 11  →  635
```

Indeed this is correct: The hexadecimal representation of 635 is `27B`. Said another way, the decimal representation of 0x27B is `635`.

### Functions!

We can make ourselves functions both to *build* and *dissect* polynomial text representations.

```
int hex_to_int( const char * text );

void int_to_hex( int number, char result[] );
```

### Digit symbols

One thing to be aware of is the number of digit symbols available to a given radix.

- For decimal we use the digit symbols `0` through `9`.
- For octal we only use the digit symbols `0` through `7`.
- For binary we only need `0` and `1`.

But we don’t have enough Arabic digit symbols for hexadecimal, which needs 16 digit symbols. So we just start using the alphabet:

→ `0` `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9` `A` `B` `C` `D` `E` `F`

Converting *to* hex is easy. Just use an array:

```
char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

To output the digit symbol for digit 13, just use the array:

```
printf( "%c", digits[13] );  // prints "D"
```

Going the other way is a little trickier. I recommend you make yourself a little function:

```
int hex_digit_to_value( int digit )
{
  if ((digit >= '0') and (digit <= '9')) return (digit - '0');
  if ((digit >= 'A') and (digit <= 'F')) return (digit - 'A') + 10;
  if ((digit >= 'a') and (digit <= 'f')) return (digit - 'a') + 10;
  return 0;  // can't happen? maybe return -1?
}
```

Comment: Slow day?? `:-)` (UV for the effort! Should be copied and distributed to every CS100 class.)

Comment: LOL, as always, I made a dumb mistake. (I tend to do a search as in **O______**’s code.) Thanks for catching that!

Comment: As Eddie Izzard notes in his performance (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKQzqwn-jIM&t=267s), "There's always one little thing..." `:-)` Outstanding answer you've written. Kudos... and Merry merry... `:-)`

Comment: [Operator synonyms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) were introduced sometime before C++17 (IDK when exactly, C++11 I think?). You can use them in C if you `#include <iso646.h>`.

Comment: My, oh my... I **did** miss the memo! Thanks for the link and the news... I may have to give up this hobby soon. "The Committee" wraps its tentacles around everything. I remember when `cat` copied files to stdout _without_ any options. As Dennis Ritchie said, "Do one thing and do it well." Now the man page for `cat` uses the full alphabet for its options, both upper & lowercase... *sigh* (getting old and don't consider these sorts of things to be improvements...) Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: Lol. I'm an Object Pascal man myself. Never did like talking in weird operator shortcuts... 